# Access subdomain on nginx server over local network

Tags: nginx, localhost, subdomain, nginx-config

I have nginx running via brew on MacOS.

I can start the nginx server, which has the default config:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}
    include servers/*;
}
```

I have configured a subdomain, test.localhost, which I can also access from the local machine:

```
server {
        listen 8080;

        root /Users/leonhughes/dev/test;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        client_max_body_size 2M; # <--for uploading large plugins

        server_name test.localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9070; # <-- this was the troublesome bit
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Over the local network, I can access the default server, (ie. http://localhost:8080 on the local machine), by typing in the IP address of the computer http:192.168.1.125:8080.

How can I access the subdomain (ie. http://test.localhost:8080 on the local machine) over the local network. I see you cannot do subdomains with ip addresses, ie. http://test.192.168.1.125:8080, and indeed this doesn't work.

I have dnsmasq installed via brew to handle the resolving. I followed this medium tutorial:

https://medium.com/@charlesthk/wordpress-on-os-x-with-nginx-php-mysql-62767a62efc4

to get Wordpress running via nginx, hence I have dnsmasq, and indeed the only export I have for dnsmasq is that in the tutorial.

I can give further details if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `192.168.1.125 test.localhost` to `/etc/hosts` for Linux clients.
Or `notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows clients.

Comment: I have tried this, performed a reboot and when I access the address http://192.168.1.125:8080 from another computer I get the default nginx website, not the subdomain

Comment: Add those to your hosts file and then navigate to: http://test.localhost/

Comment: have tried as you suggested but hasn't worked for some reason. I just get a failed to open page. No doubt this has worked for others as I have seen posts where this has worked.
I will have a look for other solutions, eg. Laravel Valet

Comment: try `server_name 192.168.1.125;`

Comment: thank you for your assistance. I have managed to get it running locally - albeit not as a subdomain - but with a different port with the ip address, so now I can do http://192.168.1.125:8081 and I can access the site from another computer.
I would like to understand why the suggestions that you made haven't worked for me, seeing that others have had no issues. I will post the code from the new test.conf for reference.

Comment: It's actually kind of surprising that test.localhost works.  Are you using the local computer as a domain controller?  That's probably why.  I'd use something like `server_name test.dev;` and then set `192.168.1.125 test.dev` in the hosts file.